# jsdoc hyphen in object key

Tags: visual-studio-code, jsdoc

An object is returned from an API which contains hyphen. I am having trouble documenting this with JSDoc in VS Code. In VS Code <s>JSDoc</s>, the hyphen and everything after the hyphen is the ignored. I have tried `Object.<string, string>` as well.

```
/**
 * @typedef MyAPIResponse
 * @type {object}
 *
 * @property {string} X-Request-Id
 * @property {string} X-Correlation-Id
 */
```

Comment: Did you try to use `@typedef` syntax from [the docs](http://usejsdoc.org/tags-typedef.html)? Like `@typedef {object} MyAPIResponse`

Comment: huh, my example and the examples in the docs actually work in jsdoc from the commandline. It doesn't work in VS Code is my issue. Updated my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved by using TypeScript declarations and [triple slash directive](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/triple-slash-directives.html).

Since I'm not using TypeScript in the project, I did the following:

1. Create a folder for types
2. Add triple slash directive to JavaScript file. Example: `<reference path="./types/my-model.d.ts" />` or use [`jsconfig.json`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/javascript#_type-checking)